# Ошибка "class, interface, or enum expected"

Tags: java

Задача на языке JAVA: создать одномерный массив, заполнить его по формуле arr[i] = Math.pow(i, i)

Мое решение:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int [] arr = {55,87,12,100,5879,4,99};
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
            arr[i] = Math.pow(i, i);
            System.out.println(arr[i]);
        }
    }


}
```

Не пойму почему выводит ошибку:Error:(35, 1) java: class, interface, or enum expected - понимаю что я не указал класс (скорее всего double).

Прошу по возможности развернуто объяснить что не так, и почему, в чем ошибка.

Comment: две закрывающие скобки `}}` в конце потеряли?

Comment: Вроде нет:                                                                                                 public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int [] arr = {55,87,12,100,5879,4,99};
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
            arr[i] = (double) Math.pow(i, i);
            System.out.println(arr[i]);
        }
    }
}

Comment: у вас в вопросе их нет. В комментарий код не надо вставлять, он там нечитаем, обновите вопрос с вашим кодом.

Comment: у вас в вопросе 7 строк кода, ошибка у вас в 35й строке.

Answer (score 0):

Нашел в чем у меня ошибка, нужно было добавить (int) в строку  arr[i] = Math.pow(i, i);. Итоговый вариант этой строки выглядит: arr[i] = (int) Math.pow(i, i);- как итог код работает.